# Get day of month from date

Tags: javascript

I have a date with the format "Wed Jun 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)", and I want to get it in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

I tried this:

```
var year = mydate.getFullYear();
var month = mydate.getMonth();
var day = mydate.getDay();
```

I got the year and the month, but I can’t get the day.

Comment: [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mydate.getDate()` to get the day-of-month number.

To get the formatting you want, you can do this.

```
var year = mydate.getFullYear();
var month = ("0" + mydate.getMonth()).slice(-2);
var day = ("0" + mydate.getDate()).slice(-2); 

var formatted = [year, month, day].join("-");
```

Comment: Look here for further explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods